# Joint probability distribution of 3 dependent variables knowing the three joint distributions for 2 variables

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose I have three discrete random variables, $x$, $y$, and $z$, which are not independent.

Suppose I know the joint probability distributions $P(x,y), P(y,z)$ and $P(x,z)$. Do I have a way to obtain $P(x,y,z)$?

Comment: You dont have anything else? Conditional distributions perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine $P(x,y,z)$, that is, $P(x,y,z)$ is not uniquely determined by the three pairwise joint distributions.  One example will suffice:

Consider $P_i(x,y,z)$ to be zero outside of  $(-1 \leq x \leq 1) \wedge (-1 \leq y \leq 1) \wedge (-1 \leq z \leq 1)  $ and define two distinct probability density functions
$$
P_1(x,y,z) = \frac14 \delta(z-1) \delta(x-y) + \frac14 \delta(z+1) \delta(x+y) \\
P_2(x,y,z) = \frac14 \delta(z-1) \delta(x+y) + \frac14 \delta(z+1) \delta(x-y) 
$$
One can immediately see that these are different probability functions; for example, the point $x = \frac12, y = \frac12, z = 1$ has non-zero probability in $P_1$ but zero probability in $P_2$.

Now compute the two-variable joint probability functions based on $P_1$:

$$P_1(x,z) = \frac14 \delta(z-1) + \frac14 \delta(z+1) \\
P_1(y,z)= \frac14 \delta(z-1) + \frac14 \delta(z+1) \\
P_1(x,y) = \frac14 \delta(x-y) + \frac14\delta(x+y)
$$
And the two-variable joint probability functions based on $P_2$ are:
$$P_2(x,z) = \frac14 \delta(z-1) + \frac14 \delta(z+1) \\
P_2(y,z)= \frac14 \delta(z-1) + \frac14 \delta(z+1) \\
P_2(x,y) = \frac14 \delta(x+y) + \frac14\delta(x-y)
$$
You cannot distinguish between $P_1(x,y,z)$ and $P_2(x,y,z)$ based on the three pairwise joint distribution functions.

This example was motivated by saying that $z$ is a discrete "switch" variable deciding whether $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

If you dislike the use of delta functions in my example, then just consider $x,y,z$ as a discrete variables with possible values $\pm 1$ andhave $P_1 = \frac14$ on the four corners of the $x,y,z$ cube with sign signature in the set $\{ (+++),(+--),(-+-), (--+) \}$ while $P_2$ is non-zero on the corners with an odd number of minus signs.  The projections along the $x, y, z$ directions of these two different distribution functions aare identical, yet the two functions are not.

Comment: Many thanks, Mark, for your answer. But what if, in addition to the three binary joint distributions, I also know the three marginal probabilities?

Comment: @Pedro Still does not determine $P(x,y,z)$.  Note that you could determine the marginal probabilities from $P(x,y), P(x,z), P(y,z)$ so it is no help if somebody does that work and tells you what they are.